# Scan Reading frame [3] Python

Tags: python, list, frame

I'm trying to write a script that can use a reading frame of 3 to detect a certain pattern and then from that sequence, go in multiples of 3 to find another pattern

```
sequence = 'TCATGAGGCTTTGGTAAATAT'
```

i need it to:

...scan with a reading frame of 3 until it finds a desired pattern (i.e. 'ATG')

...mark the location of where the first pattern ('ATG') started in the original sequence and the position of where the second pattern started ('TAA').  In this case, it would be position 3 for 'ATG' and 15 for 'TAA' .

...create a list with each triplet that follows the first pattern until it reaches the second pattern 'TAA' (i.e. 'ATG','AGG','CTT',TGG','TAA')

How do I construct a reading frame to read it in sets of 3 ? I know that once i find a way to get the reading i can create an if statement saying

```
reading_frame=[]

for frame in sequence:
    if k == 'ATG':
        reading_frame.append(k)
```

first i need the reading frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sequence = 'TCATGAGGCTTTGGTAAATAT'

frame1 = sequence.find('ATG')

my_list = []

for codon in range(len(sequence)):
    next_codon = sequence[frame1:frame1+3]
    my_list.append(next_codon)
    frame1 +=3
    if next_codon == 'TAA':
        break

print my_list
```

['ATG', 'AGG', 'CTT', 'TGG', 'TAA']

Comment: why is that when i set 

if next_codon == 'TAA' or 'TAG' or 'TGT':
    break

it doesn't work :( it only takes the 'ATG'

Comment: Sorry I am not sure why exactly. However, you can add more of that if statement with different next_codons.

Answer (score 2):

You could start by decomposing your `sequence` into a series of 3-element frames

```
sequence = 'TCATGAGGCTTTGGTAAATAT'
frames = [sequence[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(sequence),3)]
print "Frames:",frames
frames_before_ATG,frames_after_ATG = frames[:frames.index("ATG")],frames[frames.index("ATG")+1:]
```

Then iterate on the `frames` list until you find the first pattern.

Comment: it needs to start when it encounters 'ATG'

Comment: While this approach certainly might appear to be more work, it's actually probably the best (not to mention fastest), unless you're giving your script gigabytes of data that could exceed your memory. This approach will be fast, and will ensure that your start/stop codons are in the same frame. It will also simplify looking for nested reading frames, where one will start before the previous had finished (this is common in viruses and bacteria fyi).

Answer (score 1):

To find the first position of `ATG` in `sequence`, the easier is by far:

```
>>> sequence.find('ATG')
```

In your example, that gives `2`, the index of the pattern position. Then, just look for the second pattern after that position:

```
>>> idx_1 = sequence.find('ATG')
>>> idx_2 = sequence[idx_1:].find('TTA')
```

*(the `sequence[idx_1:]` returns the elements of `sequence` after position `idx_1`)*.

Keep in mind that `idx_2` is offset by `idx_1` (that is, the actual position of pattern 2 in the original list is `idx_2+idx_1`. Note that if a pattern cannot be found, the `.find` method will return -1. You may want to add some test to deal with that case.

Once you found the two patterns, you can construct the list of intermediaries as:

```
>>> subsequence = sequence[idx_1:idx_2+idx_1]
>>> [subsequence[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(subsequence), 3)]
```

You could easily iterate over a list of patterns following that example.

You may want to check whether `idx_1%3 == 0`, that is if `idx_1` is a multiple of three (assuming that the first frame starts at 0). If not, at least you know that the beginning of your sequence is to be discarded.

Comment: I think this wont necessarilly work ... since DNA is read in frames of 3 and ATG could span 2 frames ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley: quite true. Another test could be added to check whether `idx_1` is a multiple of three (assuming that the first frame starts at 0, of course).

Comment: but if its not it still doesnt rule out a later match ... i think this rapidly gets too complicated to ensure that i%3 == 0 ...

Comment: idx_2 gives me -1 . is there anyway it can give me the + value so i don't have to len(sequence) and find it that way

Comment: @draconisthe0ry: I edited my answer: -1 means that the pattern you're looking for cannot be found in the remaining of the sequence.